# Mockito 5.4.0 - When().ThenReturn() not working , always returns false. Code was working with Mockito - 1.x

Tags: mockito, java-17

```java
Class FriendlyName {

    private final ClientManager clientManger;
    
    public FriendlyName(Client client, ClientManager qcm) {        
        quasarClientManger = qcm;
    }

    public void handler(String payload) throws Exception {      

        if (clientManger.isMonitored(String, Client.class, Boolean)) {
        
            System.out.println("clientManger is true");
        } else {        
        
           System.out.println("clientManger is false");
        }
    }
}

****************************************************************************

    @Test
    public void testHandle_withKnownClient() throws Exception {

        Client cli = Mockito.mock(Client.class);
        ClientManager qcm = Mockito.mock(ClientManager.class);
        
        Mockito.when(qcm.isMonitored(Mockito.anyString(), Mockito.any(Client.class),
                Mockito.anyBoolean())).thenReturn(true);

        FriendlyName handler = new FriendlyName(cli, qcm);
        handler.handle("\"foo\"");
        Mockito.verify(mockLogger).info(Mockito.contains("clientManger is true"));
    }
    
    
****************************************************************************
```

Test always prints ""clientManger is false"" and assertion fails

We recently updated to Mockito 5.4.0 and Java 17. This code was working in Java 8, Mockito - 1.10.19

Experts! please advice.

Answer (score 0):

`Mockito.anyString()` does not match `null` (starting with [Mockito 2.1](https://github.com/mockito/mockito/wiki/What%27s-new-in-Mockito-2#incompatible)). You must use `Mockito.nullable(String.class)` with newer versions of Mockito if null arguments should be matched too.

Please note that the line `clientManger.isMonitored(String, Client.class, Boolean)` from your example does not compile, and that `any(Client.class)` does *not* match `Client.class`, but only *instances* of `Client`, such as `new Client()`. If you want to match a literal `Client.class` value (of type `Class<Client>`), you have to use `eq(Client.class)`.